# Winforms or XmlSerializer leaks?

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks

WinForms application, with one background worker, do some stuff and nothing else:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { progressBar1.Value = 0; progressBar1.Maximum = Directory.GetFiles(configuration.xml.path).Count(); }));
            Directory.GetFiles(configuration.xml.path).ToList()
                .ForEach(
                p =>
                {
                    Message = XmlSerializerHelper<message>.Read(p);
                    Message.data.ToList().ForEach(www => 
                        { 
                            if (www.state == 0)www.state = 37; 
                        }
                    );
                    try
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                        {
                            var deb1 = Message.caption.source;
                            var deb2 = configuration.periods.Single(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).name;
                            var deb3 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(o => o.Cells[0].Value.ToString()).Contains(Message.caption.source);
                            var deb4 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(o => o.Cells[1].Value.ToString()).Contains(
                                configuration.periods.Single(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).name);
                            if (!dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(o => new
                            {
                                source = o.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                                period = o.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
                            }).Contains(
                                new { 
                                    source = Message.caption.source,
                                    period = configuration.periods.Single(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).name }))                   
                            {
                                textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
                                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Message.caption.source, configuration.periods.Single(y => y.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).name, "0", "0", "0", "-");
                                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count() > 7)
                                    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height + 22);
                                dataGridView1.Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height + 22);
                                textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
                            }
                        }));
                        Message.data.Where(q => q.value.Length > 0).ToList().ForEach(r =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    r.value = r.value.Replace(',', '.');
                                    data.insObjParameterByCodeValueUpd(r.ucode, r.state, double.Parse(r.value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.Parse(r.timestamp), null);
                                    dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                        dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Single(u => 
                                            u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && 
                                            u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Single(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString())
                                            .name).Cells["lasttime"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                                    textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                            {
                                                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                                                textBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                                                textBox1.AppendText(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " загружены " + configuration.periods.Single(m=>
                                                    m.list_parperiod_id == Message.caption.datatype).name.ToLower()+ " данные за "+ Message.caption.timestamp+ " от "+ Message.caption.source + ".\r\n");
                                            })
                                        );
                                    log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " загружены " + configuration.periods.Single(m =>
                                                    m.list_parperiod_id == Message.caption.datatype).name.ToLower() + " данные за " + Message.caption.timestamp + " от " + Message.caption.source + ".\r\n");
                                    if ((bool)e.Argument)
                                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["collect"].Value =
                                        (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["collect"].Value.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
                                        }
                                          ));
                                    else
                                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["hand"].Value =
                                        (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["hand"].Value.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
                                        }
                                        ));

                                }
                                catch (Exception ww)
                                {
                                    if (!InfoMessage.Send(ww.Message, configuration.webservice.address, configuration.source.name))
                                        log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " веб сервис недоступен.\r\n");
                                    dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                            {
                                                dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["unknown"].Value =
                                                (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(u => u.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Message.caption.source.ToString() && u.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == configuration.periods.Where(c => c.list_parperiod_id.ToString() == Message.caption.datatype.ToString()).Select(c => c.name).First().ToString()).Single().Cells["unknown"].Value.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
                                            })
                                        );
                                    textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                            {
                                                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                                                textBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                                                textBox1.AppendText(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ww.Message + "\r\n");
                                                log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ww.Message + "\r\n");
                                            })
                                        );
                                    log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ww.Message + "\r\n");
                                    log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ww.Message + "\r\n");
                                }
                            });

                        if (!checkBox2.Checked)
                            File.Delete(p);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e11)
                    {
                        if (!InfoMessage.Send(e11.Message, configuration.webservice.address, configuration.source.name))
                            log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " веб сервис недоступен.\r\n");
                        textBox1.Invoke(
                            new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                {
                                    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                                    textBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                                    textBox1.AppendText(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + e11.Message + "\r\n");
                                    log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + e11.Message + "\r\n");
                                })
                            );
                        log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + e11.Message + "\r\n");
                    }
                    progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { progressBar1.Value++; }));
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            if (!InfoMessage.Send(ee.Message, configuration.webservice.address, configuration.source.name))
                log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " веб сервис недоступен.\r\n");
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                        textBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                        textBox1.AppendText(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ee.Message + "\r\n");
                    })
            );
            log.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ee.Message + "\r\n"); 
        }
    }
```

XmlSerializer:

```
public static class XmlSerializerHelper<T>
{
    public static Type _type = typeof(T);



    public static MemoryStream Save(object obj) {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_type);
        var memstr = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(memstr, obj,ns);
        return memstr;
    }
    public static void Save(string path, object obj)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_type);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj, ns);
        }

    }

    public static T Read(string path)
    {
        T result;
        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(_type);
            result = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this stuff repeats every 10 second, by timer.
after 2 weaks of working this application have 150Mb of memory.
What can leak here?

Comment: How much memory does it use after 1 day, 2 days, 1 week, 2 weeks, 4 weeks?  Does it increase or is it being recycled?

Comment: its increasing. begins from 30-40Mb, and then linearly increases

Comment: Over what period of time?  I'd expect it to increase initially, but does it ever (significantly) go above 150Mb?  Note that it's important that you use the same machine to perform all tests.  I agree with Marc's answer below, but this will help put your mind at ease that there is no leak.

Comment: @Jack you still haven't answered my question of *how you are measuring this* - it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after 2 weaks of working this application have 150Mb of memory.

Nothing; that's doing just fine. Memory is there *to be used*, and apps needn't by overly shy about using it. It doesn't sound like it is haemorrhaging memory; let it be.

Comment: (comment by @JackBrown that was on a deleted accidental duplicate): no. if it starts from 20Mb, why memory increases? it will fail out of memory one day. do not want

Comment: @JackBrown has it ever failed out of memory? The system responds to things like *memory pressure*; i.e. ***demand*** for memory. If nothing is competing for memory.... also: how are you measuring this? because most numbers (including those in task manager) *are a lie*.

Answer (score 0):

**The XmlSerializer [suffers a memory leak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886385/en-us)**.

I do not know if it stills happens in .NET 4.0, but it stills remains in .NET 3.5.

Because you are running a winforms application, it is not that bad because resources are released when the application closes - if it closes...

I experienced this case by writing a windows service where I use intensive XML Serialization and other unmanaged resources. The unmanaged code crashed because of memory outage and I struggled to find where it comes from.

The **XmlSerializerCache** of **the [mvpxml library](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com)** saves my life.